The scope of animation with in LazyColumn Item view
I have a LazyColumn,and the item view has Image,button.at the bottom of page, it has a cart icon.so when click the button of item,image will be start an offset animation that adds the bottom shopping cart icon.but the scope of animation just within the  item view.in effect,I hope the destination of animation is bottom of this page. because the cart icon is in the bottom of page, so, I don't know how to solve this problem, Any one help me? thanks a lot!
some code snippet:
@Composable
fun GoodsListView() {
    var itemAddedToCart by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val cartPosition = remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    val animatedOffset by animateOffsetAsState(
        targetValue = if (itemAddedToCart) cartPosition.value else Offset.Zero,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing), label = ""
    )
    val scale by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (itemAddedToCart) 0f else 1f,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing), label = ""
    )
    Column {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            items(list.size) {
                Row {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_mall_goods_default_icon), // the original of image
                        contentDescription = "Goods Cover",
                        modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)
                    )
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .offset { IntOffset(animatedOffset.x.toInt(), animatedOffset.y.toInt()) }
                            .size(100.dp)
                            .graphicsLayer {
                                scaleX = scale
                                scaleY = scale
                            }
                    ) {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_mall_goods_default_icon), // the target of animation image
                            contentDescription = "",
                            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)
                        )
                    }
                    Button(onClick = {
                        if (!itemAddedToCart) itemAddedToCart = true
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Add to cart")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_mall_cart), // the destination of animation
            contentDescription = "Shopping Cart",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
                    cartPosition.value = layoutCoordinates.positionInRoot()
                }
        )
    }
}

I have no more experience with compose,so ask for here.
